# OpenWRT CC Attitude Adjustment

Tags: router, openwrt, opkg

I would like to install syslog-ng3 on my OpenWRT Router and the standard opkg packages do not involve syslog-ng3.

About my router:

- Model: ZBT-7620
- Firmware: OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05 r48749 / LuCI branch (git-16.074.41553-6fa1ae3)
- Kernel Version:

So I have tried to install it through the attitude adjustment package:

```
root@ZBT:~# opkg install http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09-rc1/ramips/rt305x/packages/syslog-ng3_3.0.5-5_ramips.ipk
```

but I get the following error:

```
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09-rc1/ramips/rt305x/packages/syslog-ng3_3.0.5-5_ramips.ipk.
Unknown package 'syslog-ng3'.
Collected errors:
 * pkg_hash_fetch_best_installation_candidate: Packages for syslog-ng3 found, but incompatible with the architectures configured
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package syslog-ng3.
```

How can I install the package?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to build the packages and then install the packages manually

Comment: Your going to have to also target your routers architecture might even involve building OpenWRT and including the package itself.  How that's done is documented by OpenWRT

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Well, I have downloaded the package with wget, but I do not know how to build and install it manually. 
Could you help again?

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error because the architecture was not same. You are having Chaos Calmer and you were installing package for Attitude Adjustment.
There is no syslog-ng3 for chaos calmer(rt305x). There is syslog-ng package available for trunk version, I don't know it will support CC, try it and for configuration of syslog-ng refer this [link](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/openwrt-syslog-ng-installation/).
For syslog-ng download it from this [link](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ramips/rt305x/packages/packages/syslog-ng_3.9.1-1_ramips.ipk).
For what purpose you exactly need syslog-ng3 if you tell that, then I think I will help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it. I am trying to log all source MAC addresses and destination IPs which are going out from my router. I will log which client visits which website.

Comment: Then, refer this [link](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=54048) post no-5. You need not to install any additional packages.

Comment: If you find this answer useful then mark it as correct one. So other also can refer this.